# How large should a database table grow?

Tags: postgresql, database-size

I have been experiencing some very slow queries for a specific table. This table grows daily. I ran the pg_relation_size function, which gives the size of a table in the database:

```
mydb=# select pg_relation_size('reports');
 pg_relation_size 
------------------
      10318856192
(1 row)
```

Now I assume the return value is in bytes. So if I wanted gigabyte size, then this is basically saying 10.3 gigabytes. Could a table that is in 10 gigabytes in size really reduce the performance of queries against that table?

Comment: Do you run `vacuum` on your table regularly. That will garbage collect and reclaim storage. More info [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-vacuum.html)

Comment: How many rows does the table have? And what is the definition of the table? What kind of columns does it contain?

Comment: `pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('reports'))` for human readable. Table size vs query performance depends on indexes, clustering, query patterns, and more; show `explain analyze` for queries you're concerned about. Also make sure the table isn't bloated (see vacuum documentation, postgresql wiki on routine vacuuming).